# Run-time error '1004' The command requires at least two rows of source data

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, would really appreciate any help / tips.

I wish to automate the range for the advanced filter function, so that the last row at the time of import of each subsequent section is stored in a different `iRow_number`, that can be used to store the references for automation.

The non-automated method works, but the automated doesn't and it's driving me up the wall as I can't figure out why. The error I am getting is

> "Run-time error '1004': This command requires at least two rows of
>   source data. You cannot use the command on a selection in only one
>   row. Try the following: If you're using an advanced filter, select a
>   range of cells that contains at least two rows of data. Then click the
>   advanced filter command again. If you're creating a PivotTable report
>   or"...(not relevant).

Please help !

Attached is my code.

```
Dim iRow3 As Long

Sub Filter()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim iRow1 As Long
Dim iRow2 As Long
Dim cell1 As Long
Dim cell2 As Long

Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'import_filter_criteria()

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\XXXXXXX" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "filter_criteria"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

iRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

'import_Headings()

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\XXXXXXXX" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$" & (iRow1 + 1)))
    .Name = "headings"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With


iRow2 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

'import_Data()

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\XXXXXXX" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$" & (iRow2)))
    .Name = "mass_evol_db"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 2
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 5, 9, 1, 5, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(4, 13, 1, 8, 11, 1, 8, 3, 11, 11, 11, 11, 14, 14, 14, _
    14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 _
    , 6, 6, 6, 15, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

iRow3 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

' filter_in_action()
```

THIS METHOD WORKS, but isn't automated in the ranges

```
Range("A15:BO253").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
Range("A1:BO13"), CopyToRange:=Range("$A$" & (iRow3 + 1)), Unique:=False
```

THESE TWO METHODs DON'T WORK

```
Range(Cells((iRow1 + 1), 1), Cells((iRow2 - 2), 67)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells((iRow1 - 1), 67)), CopyToRange:=Range("$A$" & (iRow3 + 1)), Unique:=False

Range("A" & (iRow1 + 1) & ":BO" & (iRow2 - 2)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
Range("A1:BO" & (iRow1 - 1)), CopyToRange:=Range("$A$" & (iRow3 + 1)), Unique:=False
```

Comment: For the methods that aren't working for you, what do `iRow1` and `iRow2` evaluate to?

Comment: iRow1 = 14, iRow 2 = 255, iRow 3 = 275. The reason why I have got (iRow1 + 1) etc. is because I want a blank row between some sections for ease of looking at the data

Comment: Oops I see my issue. The offsets I've put in don't match what I want. *facepalm*

Comment: Even after trying it again, it still hasn't worked (I've edited the original post to correct the initial mistake I had though) :( Any further ideas would be welcome, thank you !

Comment: honestly the only reason i could possibly imagine is that your iRow values are wrong. put a debug.print iRow1 & "  " & iRow 2 just before your not working methods and check the result. Sorry if you have allready done that, but it is hard to imagine an erro on another part =)

Comment: or `debug.print Range(Cells(iRow+1,1), Cells(iRow2-2,67)).Address` to make sure the Range is evaluating correctly - but it looks OK.

Comment: Thank you all, I solved my problem, I was incorrectly using Row 2, when I should have used Row 3, silly mistake, but thank you !